# Force recalculation of GetDate() for each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, getdate

When running this command in SQL Server Management Studio

```
UPDATE LogChange 
SET Created = GETDATE() 
WHERE id > 6000
```

something strange happens.. :)

All rows get the same value in the `Created` column.

How do I "force" SQL Server to recalculate the `GetDate` for every row?

Comment: this will set the column 'Created' to the current getdate() value if the id is greater than 6000, what were you expecting?

Comment: That is what i was expectig :) but not all 4M lines to become the same date :)

Comment: what date were you expecting?

Comment: Why not try using Case Statement?

Comment: To get slightly offset of the GetDate for each line. Seems like the GetDate is calculated first then reused for every row

Comment: You're right, the getdate() will be declared once and then used for all rows. You'll want a cursor to do a separate statement for each row. That's going to cost a lot though.

Comment: A coursor is probably the easiest way. I was just suprised that it workd that way

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. As much as possible, where you ask it to perform an activity with a set, it will produce results which are consistent ("as-if") all of the activity occurred in parallel. It doesn't work row-by-row. Or, if it does, it tries to conceal this fact from you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a scalar function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.sf_GetDate(@num int)
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN GETDATE()
END
GO
```

Then use it like this:

```
UPDATE LogChange 
SET Created = dbo.GetDate(Id) 
WHERE id > 6000
```

Answer (score 0):

A cursor solved it

```
declare @id int;

Declare toLoop  cursor for 
select Id from LogChange where id > 6000

 OPEN toLoop
 FETCH NEXT FROM toLoop INTO @id  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    Update LogChange set Created = GETDATE() where id = @id

    FETCH NEXT FROM toLoop INTO @id  
END  

close toLoop
DEALLOCATE toLoop
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you'd want this? Performance-wise this isn't very slick.

Comment: To get unique values in the Created col. It's a one time job so it's really not a problem that it takes some time

Comment: @PEtter - you're not guaranteed unique values here though. You're assuming that the cursor will never run fast enough such that it could assign two (or more) rows the same value. Since `GETDATE()` only changes values every ~3ms, that's far from certain in all circumstances.

Comment: Even if you went all the way down to System Tick you would eventually have collisions.  You have to use an identity column or a sequence or a guid to get unique values.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following “getdate()” pattern extremely useful over the years.  Especially when updating multiple tables in the same transaction.  Having the time values exactly match had more benefit to me then being accurate to the millisecond on individual rows.

```
declare @dtNow datetime 

SET @dtNow = GETDATE()

UPDATE LogChange 
SET Created = @dtNow
WHERE id > 6000
```

Comment: Actually, `GETDATE()` returns a `DATETIME` and therefore is only accurate to 3.33ms  :-)  If you *need* millisecond precision, use `SYSDATETIME()` which returns a `DATETIME2(7)` datatype value - accurate down to 100ns (yes - **nano**seconds!)

Comment: Thank you marc_s my goal here was just to generate unique values in the created column.  So the SYSDATETIME() helped me a lot : )

Comment: But this is the opposite of what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do them in a single query because the operations in the same clause of a query are evaluated all-at-once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *guarantee* that separate values are applied to each row, write a query that definitely does that:

```
declare @dt datetime
set @dt = GETDATE()

;With Diffs as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) * 10 as Offset
    from
        LogChange
    WHERE id > 6000
)
UPDATE Diffs 
SET Created = DATEADD(millisecond,Offset,@dt)
```

We know that the above will generate separate offsets for each row, and that we're definitely adding those offsets to a fixed value. It has often been *observed* that `GETDATE()` will return the same value for all rows but I cannot find any specific documentation that guarantees this, which is why I've also introduced a `@dt` variable so that I know it's only assigned once.