# Using GetDate() as part of SELECT DISTINCT cannot be good?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am reviewing some SQL that looks as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyField, GETDATE()
FROM MyTable
```

Now even though the query takes longer than 1ms I receive the expected number of records. And each record has the DateTime down to the same millisecond and in fact produces the same number as records as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MyField
FROM MyTable
```

Can anyone point me at any documentation or provide some other insights as to what the "rules" are that make this behaviour what it is in SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server tries to treat the entire query as a set based operation.  Hence `GETDATE` is called once, cached, and the value is then reused for every record in the result set.  This is why adding `GETDATE` to your query does not change the count.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011671/sql-server-update-caches-value-of-getdate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GETDATE()` and `RAND()` are canonical examples of runtime-constant functions.  That means that the function is called once when the command is started, not for every row.

This is alluded to in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190642(v=sql.105).aspx):

> Aside from runtime constant nondeterministic built-ins RAND, and the
>   GETDATE family, the number, order, and timing of calls will depend on
>   the plan chosen.

(From what I can tell, the documentation does not go into this in excruciating detail.)

Hence, `GETDATE()` is a constant for the query, not evaluated for each row.